# Symfony2 - Get an entity instead of PersistentCollection in twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony2, and I can't manage to get my related entity in twig.

So I have my main entity, let's call it Post, which has a OneToMany relation :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="Post", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $comments;
```

And I'm passing it to twig with my controller, I can access every property, but when I try to access a property with relations like "Comment", i'm getting a  *"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)"*  which has a lot of private property, and I can't manage to get the properties of this related entity...

I'm a little confused, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are trying to access a collection of entities directly.
You have to loop your comments collection :

```
{% for comment in post.comments %}
    // You can get your comment entity here 
    // for example
    <p>{{comment.description}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, what confused me must be I only have 1 comment on my post, so I supposed it's why I was trying to access it directly, need some coffee i guess ..

Comment: This is the same in php btw; foreach($post->getComments() as $comment) { dump($comment->getDescription()); }

Answer (score 10):

**Get First item of the doctrine collection in twig**

if you have only 1 object on the collection then you can get it by using the `first` method

```
{% set comment = post.comments.first %}
```

[PersistentCollection: first() method](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html#_first)

**Convert DoctrineCollection to array in twig**

To convert the doctrine collection to an array you can use the getValues() method :

```
{% set arrayComment = post.comments.getValues %}
```

[PersistentCollection: getValues() method](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html#_getValues)